# intellij error while importing SBT project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, ubuntu-16.04

I recently installed IntelliJ on Ubuntu 16.04, but I'm getting this error while trying to start a Scala project:

[image]

This is my first linux computer, and I installed the oracle 8 jdk through the package manager, not sure if it's something wrong with this configuration or something else. Am I missing some java variables? When I installed intellij before on Windows the scala package came with basically everything I needed, and I used the jdk windows installer.

Comment: have you set JAVA_HOME in ubuntu??

Comment: `echo $JAVA_HOME` returns `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle`

Comment: please try again after deleting "~/.sbt/boot" and "~/.sbt/repositories".

Answer (score 0):

I think your Intellij is missing the Scala SDK. Usually it would be picked during first time setup.

Open "Open Module Settings" of your project (by right-click), go to libraries, add an Scala SDK.

Hope it should fix your problem.

Comment: It was missing the Scala SDK, but after adding one, it still came up with the same error. For some reason, it is using `scala-sdk-2.10.6`, and when I try to download 2.12, it gives me a download error saying "0 artifacts copied, 5 already retrieved, Error: Could not retrieve Scala 2.10.6: missing scala.Option"